# Write interval time samples to file

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
private static void LogTime(IList<TimeSpan> timeList)
{
    TimeSpan frameTimeDuration = timeList[1] - timeList[0];
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\practice\Desktop\LogPauseTime1.txt", FileMode.Append))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {                       
            for(int i = 0; i<timeList.Count(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < timeList.Count() - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (timeList[j + 1] - timeList[j] == frameTimeDuration)
                    {
                        j = j + 1;
                    }                                
                    else
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", timeList[i].ToString(), timeList[j].ToString());
                        i = i + 1;                                
                        i=j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`timeList` consists of such values:

[image]
I need to write to the file such values:

```
00:00:00.5760000 - 00:00:01.0080000
00:00:42.6240000 - 00:00:43.0560000
```

....
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

This is my output. Result should be 00:00:00.0260000 - 00:00:09.4820000

```
00:00:00.0260000 - 00:00:01.3840000
00:00:01.4110000 - 00:00:02.6640000
00:00:02.6910000 - 00:00:03.9440000
00:00:03.9710000 - 00:00:05.2240000
00:00:05.2510000 - 00:00:06.5040000
00:00:06.5310000 - 00:00:07.7840000
00:00:07.8110000 - 00:00:09.0640000
00:00:09.1170000 - 00:00:09.2730000
00:00:09.3260000 - 00:00:09.4820000
```

Comment: Put `timeList ` in text form please

Comment: Why is `break;` before `i=j;`?

Comment: What is your expected method on the grouping? How to tell a proper `frameTimeDuration`?

Comment: frameTime - it is min possible value beetween two time values.

Comment: What's your current output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution (if i understand your logic):

```
public void PrintLog(IList<TimeSpan> timeList, TimeSpan frameTime, string logFileName)
{
    int count = timeList.Count;
    if (count != 0)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                int beginIndex;
                TimeSpan begin = timeList[beginIndex = 0];
                for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
                {
                    if (timeList[i] - begin > frameTime)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", begin, timeList[i - 1]);
                        begin = timeList[beginIndex = i];
                    }
                }

                // last interval
                if (beginIndex <= count - 1)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", timeList[beginIndex], timeList[count - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PrintLog(timeList, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) /* or timeList[1] - timeList[0] */, @"D:\Temp\output.txt" /* or your file name */);
```

Answer (score 1):

In linq version

```
private static void LogTime(IList<TimeSpan> timeList, TimeSpan maxFrameSize, string logFilePath)
{
    var groupedTimes = timeList
        .OrderBy(i=>i)
        .GroupAdjacentBy((current, next) => next - current <= maxFrameSize)
        .Select(g => new {FromTime = g.First(), ToTime = g.Last()});

    var file = new System.IO.FileInfo(logFilePath);
    using (var writer = file.AppendText())
    {
        foreach (var times in groupedTimes)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", times.FromTime, times.ToTime);
        }
    }
}
```

With this linq extension

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupAdjacentBy<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                var pred = e.Current;
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (predicate(pred, e.Current))
                    {
                        list.Add(e.Current);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return list;
                        list = new List<T> { e.Current };
                    }
                    pred = e.Current;
                }
                yield return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```